# Overlapping Date Ranges Summarized

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

​A parent company owns companies with employees.  Each company can hire and term an employee.
An employee can work for multiple companies at the same time.

Within a company, hire and term dates cannot overlap, but they can across companies.  A hire date is considered to be a person's first day of employment, and a term date is considered to be a person's last day of employment.

A person can have many periods of employment (leave and return).  Active employees have a term date of '9999-12-31'.

**How do I get a result set of a person's hire and term dates for the parent company ignoring overlapping dates?**

Source Table:

```
+--------------+----------+-------------+-------------+
| ​employee_id  | company​  | hire_date​   |  term_date​  |
+--------------+----------+-------------+-------------+
| ​1            | A​        | 2017-01-01​  | 2017-07-01​  |
| ​1            | A        | 2018-01-01​  | 2018-06-15​  |
| ​1            | B​        | 2018-04-01​  | 9999-12-31​  |
+--------------+----------+-------------+-------------+
```

Desired result:

```
+--------------+-------------+-------------+
| ​employee_id  |  hire_date​  | term_date​   |
+--------------+-------------+-------------+
| ​1            | 2017-01-01​  | 2017-07-01​  |
| ​1            | 2018-01-01​  | 9999-12-31​  |
+--------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no question. No sign of research or effort. Just a need.

Comment: Thanks @HABO for the article on writing a better question.  I'll be sure to incorporate that in future questions.  After considerable research and effort, all were all dead ends, and I considered them to be distracting to the core question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from SQL Server 2012 you can use `LAG` (more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)) to compare values between different lines of a table:

```
declare @tmp table (employee_id int, company varchar(10), hire_date date, term_date date)
insert into @tmp values
 (1,'','2017-01-01','2017-07-01')
,(1,'','2018-01-01','2018-06-15')
,(1,'','2018-04-01','9999-12-31')

 ​  ​
select employee_id, min(hire_date) as hire_date, max(term_date) as term_date
from
(
  select employee_id, hire_date, term_date, max (tmp1) over (partition by employee_id order by hire_date asc) as tmp2
  from
  (
    SELECT employee_id,
           hire_date,
           isnull (term_date, '9999-12-31') term_date,
           case
             when
               (hire_date not between lag(hire_date) over (partition by employee_id order by hire_date asc)
                   and isnull( lag(term_date) over (partition by employee_id order by hire_date asc), '9999-12-31') )
                or lag(hire_date) over (partition by employee_id order by hire_date asc) is null
                then
                  row_number() over (partition by employee_id order by hire_date asc)
             end as tmp1
    FROM @tmp
  ) x
) y
group by employee_id, tmp2
```

Results:

[image]